# Why can't the content in "UNSUBSCRIBE" be edited? How to add some text?

Tags: sendgrid, unsubscribe

[image: Why can't the content in "UNSUBSCRIBE" be edited? How to add some text?]

Why can't the content in "UNSUBSCRIBE" be edited? How to add some text?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is in no way related to programming. Did you try to contact the customer support of whatever service you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the unsubscribe links, but not in the unsubscribe widget. Instead, you should add a regular text or code widget and use the tag `{{{unsubscribe}}}` for the URL. See the documentation here for more details on [using a custom unsubscribe link](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/create-and-manage-unsubscribe-groups#using-a-custom-unsubscribe-link).

Comment: I know that you can add unsubscribe hyperlinks in "Marketing->Single Sends", but there is no place to add hyperlinks in "Email API->Dynamic Templates->TEMPLATE->settings" ?

Comment: It’s not in the settings, you put the link in your template itself.

Comment: @twillio @sendgrid does the solution above still work as of today (2022/12)?
I added something like this in a dynamic template but it seems not working.


`<div style="font-family: inherit; text-align: center"><a href="{{{unsubscribe}}}"><u>メール配信停止</u></a></div>`

Comment: @OtaniShuzo I would recommend you start a new question and give all the details about what is not working. Hopefully someone can then help you out.